# Creating an employee Permission DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I work for a small company that has many different permissions for different apps. Right now we track all of this on a spreadsheet that is slowly getting out of control. We look in a column, to match of a job grouping (say accounting- finance might be a group), then look at each row below that to find out how many applications they need, and the needed permissions for each application. Then with this information we go about giving them the access. I'd like to automate this whole thing at some point. But for now I'm focused on removing the spreadsheet

I'd like to make a simple database that would allow me to query and search by Logical Job group, and pull back the permissions for each individual app that pertain to that job grouping. I haven't worked in building databases before but I've installed SQL express, just need some help logically thinking out the tables and how they would interact. Each application obviously can have different permission groups, but can also contain mutliple. For example, Employee A, needs application X installed, with permission groups 1, 2, and 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would design an Applications table, a Roles table a Users table and a Permissions table. They would be related like this:

Users is related to Roles, one User may have many Roles.

Applications is related to Roles. One Application may have many Roles.

Roles is related to both Applications and Permissions. One Role may belong to one more Applications, and have one or more Permissions.

Permissions is related to Roles. Each permission belongs to a specific Role.

Hope this at the very least gives you and idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This requires more than installing SQL express. You need to figure out architecture i.e how your data relates to each other at different points. In your case granting permissions doesn't look like a database operation. Permissions for different applications should better be handled manually by admins(compliance). What you can do is you can store the job groupings and there required permissions in database, automate the front end i.e requesting access, for that you can use Microsoft Flow application which lets you connect to different apps, databases etc. and based on input provided by the user you can search for accesses to be given in database and send it to admin/automate if its a database application or if you can connect to any other application's admin console from MS Flow.